# Openpyxl Border line breaks on intersection with another border line

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a table to tabulate data with python's third party excel package, openpyxl.
The first for statement of the code draws a row line from cell 'A5' to cell 'E5',
The second for statement draws another row line from cell 'A6' to cell 'E6'
The third for statement draws a column line from cell 'C5' to cell 'C9'
The fourth for statement draws another column from cell 'F5 to cell 'F9'

However, the column border drawn from cell 'C5' to 'C9' seems to break just
when it intersects the row lines from cell 'A5 to 'E5' and 'A6' to 'E6',and
starts drawing at 'C7' instead of 'C5'.

While the column border line drawn from cell 'F5':'F9' worked perfectly fine.
(I would have posted an image of the table being created but i have a less-than-10 reputation)
Is there anything i'm doing wrong somewhere?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.sheet_view.showGridLines = False

column_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'))
row_border = Border(top=Side(style='thin'))

for col in ws['C5:C9']:
    for cell in col:
        cell.border = column_border
for col in ws['F5:F9']:
    for cell in col:
        cell.border = column_border

for row in ws['A5:E5']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.border = row_border
for col in ws['A6:E6']:
    for cell in col:
        cell.border = row_border

wb.save('a.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are over-writing the Border object of those cells where they intersect.  Your first two loops set the Border object of cells to be a Thin Line on the Left side.  The next two loops set the Border Object of the cells to be a a Thin Line on the Top - but this gets rid of the original Border object that created the top line.

What I would recommend doing is create two methods add the border object.  The methods would check if the border already exists.  If it does, it would augment it rather than replace it.  Then you call these methods in your loops rather than do the direct assignment.

This code may or may not work, my current system doesn't have OpenPyXL installed and I need admin privileges to install it.

```
def add_row_boarder(row_cell):
    if row_cell.border = None:
        row_cell.border = row_border
    else:
        row_cell.border.top = Side(style='thin')
    return row_cell

def add_col_boarder(col_cell):
    if col_cell.border = None:
        col_cell.border = col_border
    else:
        col_cell.border.left = Side(style='thin')
    return col_cel
```

Answer (score 1):

As Rob notes, you're overwriting the borders of some cells. A generic approach to formatting a range of cells is provided by the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#styling-merged-cells) but basically you can just combine styles so `cell.border = cell.border + row_border`